# Export satellite images for an entire country from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

How can I download all the satellite images covering an entire country(Kenya) for a period of years from Google Earth Engine? I drew a large geometry polygon over the entire country and then tried to get the images by using filterBounds() but doesnt seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
var roi = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.FeatureCollection(
    [ee.Feature(
        ee.Geometry.Polygon(
            [[[41.484375, -1.6477220517969224],
              [39.5068359375, 3.447624666646865],
              [35.2880859375, 4.981505049328245],
              [33.99169921875, 4.23685605976896],
              [34.98046875, 2.1088986592431382],
              [33.99169921875, -0.9447814006873896],
              [39.2431640625, -4.740675384778361]]]),
        {
          "system:index": "0"
        })]);



var image = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD09A1')
.filterBounds(roi)
.filterDate('2010-01-01', '2013-12-31')
.sort('CLOUD_COVER')
.first()
);
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['sur_refl_b01', 'sur_refl_b03', 
'sur_refl_b04'], max: 0.5, gamma: 2}, "Modis Image");
```

Comment: Depends on the country and the desired scale. The whole US would be difficult anyhow, but e.g. the Netherlands on a scale of 1:200.000 you could do manually.
Using QGis and a WMS, you could build a script, that exports the current screen as a geotiff, then moves to the next cell of a predefined raster and does the same and so on. Some more details would be helpful.

Comment: I want satellite data on surface reflectance, land cover and temperature from MODIS  for the entire country of Kenya from 2003-2015

Comment: It is indeed possible, but might not be very useful. What have you tried so far? There are multiple tutorials on filtering the data and exporting results. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/) is a good starting point.

Comment: Then why do you want to use google earth? Why not directly download the data from NASA?

Comment: You could try to dive deeper on GEE and process the images with it, you can always ask for help in here =)

Comment: I have updated the problem with more information.

Comment: It is working fine. The images in the modis imagecollection you're using are global. If you only want the portion of the image in your ROI, you must cilp it (or them). Assuming there are multiple images in your date range, I believe you need to write a little function that uses the ee.Image.clip command. As a side note, searching the EE developer's forum is immensely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that MODIS doesn't have CLOUD_COVER metadata, so filtering for it returns no image.  The MODIS images you're accessing are global, so that sort of metadata doesn't make any sense.

Also, your scaling is off (you need to specify a min and the images are scaled by 0.0001.

```
var image = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD09A1')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2013-12-31')
  .first());
Map.addLayer(image, {
  bands: ['sur_refl_b01', 'sur_refl_b04', 'sur_refl_b03'], min:0, max: 4000},
  "Modis Image");
```